# Including/excluding globs for gulp.src

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, glob, minimatch

I'm trying to setup a glob array for my javascript concat build task in *gulp*. The directory structure looks as follows:

```
├── about
│   └── about.js
├── assets
├── contact
├── core
│   ├── navbar
│   │   ├── navbar.js
│   │   └── navbar.test.js
│   ├── routing.js
│   ├── routing.test.js
│   ├── utils.js
│   └── utils.test.js
├── generated
│   ├── footer.js
│   ├── header.js
│   └── templates.js
├── home
├── app.js
└── config.js
```

The order of the files is important:

1. generated/header.js
2. app.js
3. any of the *.js files, except those here below
4. generated/templates.js
5. generated/footer.js

I've *wildly* tried all kinds of wildcards combination, but the globbing isn't strong with me.

```
var inputFiles = [
  'generated/header.js',
  'app.js',
  '!(generated)**/*.js',    // <=---- ???
  'generated/templates.js',
  'generated/footer.js',
  '!**/*.test.js'
];
```

So how do I include all `*.js` files except those from a subdirectory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best I came up with:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var tap = require('gulp-tap');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'generated/header.js',
        'app.js',
        '*.js',
        './!(generated)/**/*.js', // <- All subdirs except 'generated'
        'generated/{templates,footer}.js',
        '!**/*.test.js',
        '!node_modules/**'
    ]).pipe(tap(function(file) {
        console.log(file.path);
    }));
});
```

Running it:

```
∴ glob-test gulp
[20:07:51] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/glob-test/gulpfile.js
[20:07:51] Starting 'default'...
/Users/heikki/Desktop/glob-test/generated/header.js
/Users/heikki/Desktop/glob-test/app.js
/Users/heikki/Desktop/glob-test/config.js
/Users/heikki/Desktop/glob-test/gulpfile.js
/Users/heikki/Desktop/glob-test/about/about.js
/Users/heikki/Desktop/glob-test/core/routing.js
/Users/heikki/Desktop/glob-test/core/utils.js
/Users/heikki/Desktop/glob-test/core/navbar/navbar.js
/Users/heikki/Desktop/glob-test/generated/templates.js
/Users/heikki/Desktop/glob-test/generated/footer.js
[20:07:51] Finished 'default' after 326 ms
```

The main trick is avoiding the "!" character at the beginning of glob when including files.

https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch#comparisons-to-other-fnmatchglob-implementations

**"If the pattern starts with a ! character, then it is negated."**

ps. Placement of the negated globs doesn't matter. They are always moved to the end behind the scenes.

Comment: Be careful with this - any glob whose first character is not '!' uses [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) for glob-matching, not minimatch, and node-glob negation "is deprecated in version 5, and will be removed entirely in version 6". Therefore globs like `'./!(generated)/**/*.js'` won't work in version 6 (at least, as far as I can tell).

Comment: Second point: negated globs aren't always moved to the end. They are filtered through in order. Have a look at the [source](https://github.com/wearefractal/glob-stream/blob/799c843870735021613b37fb486b7545a6cb3ea0/index.js#L123).