# Node glob pattern for every .js file except .spec.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, glob, grunt-usemin

I am looking for a better glob pattern for usemin, i want to to find all `.js` files but exclude the `.spec.js` files. I have the following solution so far.

`<script src="components/**/*(.js|!(*.spec.js|*.scss))"></script>`

The solution i have at the moment requires me to keep adding file extensions to exclude them, else they get picked up, for example `.html` files.

I tried to make it only look for `.js` files and exclude the `.spec.js` from them but it does not seem to work.

Also adding a `!components/**/*.spec.js` as another script below does not seem to work.

Comment: You may be able to exclude those test scripts with a glob pattern, but perhaps a better approach would be to put them in a separate `test` directory at the same level as `components`. That way they're easily excluded from your build process.

Comment: Agreed +1 and I have many times, but this time I have a component based folder structure with code and spec together.

Comment: I renamed `*.spec.js` files to just `*.spec`.

Answer (score 168):

This glob includes all `*.js` but not `*.spec.js`:

```
components/**/!(*.spec).js
```

Comment: What if I have more files to ignore, like *.controller.js, *.module.js, etc? I'm trying to modify your answer to work but without success so far.

Comment: Ok I figured it out: `components/**/!(*.spec|*.controller).js`

Comment: What does it compile to? I just imagined it as "components/**/*.!(spec).js" I thinking regex way. Why star is not negated between the brackets?

Comment: from another post I've read that the node-glob negation using '!' "is deprecated in version 5, and will be removed entirely in version 6": [see post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563048/including-excluding-globs-for-gulp-src)

Comment: A guess for `all *.spec.js but not *.js` → `components/**/*.spec.js`

Comment: @Lajos 'cause that's how glob works? :) https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#glob-primer