# node-glob match all files but a single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob, node-glob

I'm trying to write a glob pattern that matches all files `*.*` but not `index.html`.

I started with: `*.*!(index.html)`, but this doesn't result in the correct output.

I'm reading [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer) documentation.

After looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639236/node-glob-pattern-for-every-js-file-except-spec-js)

I feel it may not be achievable...?

I don't want to use the exclude option in the glob options, I want to try and do it using the glob pattern alone.

Answer (score 2):

This is old I know, but I wanted something similar.  The answer is you're misinterpreting the docs: to match all files but not index.html is just `!(index.html)`. You don't need the `*.*`. So, for example, to match all files in your dist folder and subfolders, but not index.html, would be `./dist/**/!(index.html)`.